# Is there any maven plugin for JAXB 3.0 (Jakarta EE 9)?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jaxb, maven-plugin

Current maven plugins like jaxb2-maven-plugin and maven-jaxb2-plugin generate code using the package javax.xml instead of the new jakarta.xml package of Jakarta EE. It seems there's no way of configure any of them to use JAXB 3.0. Is there any maven plugin for JAXB 3.0?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the source/target (release) compatibility for the projects below is at Java 11, up from Java 8. And, JDK 17 is used for the build. JAXB dependencies are at version 4.x for [Jakarta EE 10](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/).

- [hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) - Maven plugin for JAXB 4.x forked from *maven-jaxb2-plugin*.
- [hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) - JAXB 4.x plugins forked from *jaxb2-basics*.

Here [hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-jaxbplugins-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-jaxbplugins-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip) is a sample project and to learn more see [HiSrc Sample JAXB Plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/tree/master/assembly/samples/jaxbplugins#readme).

> Note: The [4.x](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/4.0/) release of the JAXB [API](https://github.com/jakartaee/jaxb-api/tree/4.0.0-RELEASE), [RI](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/tree/4.0.2-RI-RELEASE/jaxb-ri) and [ZIP](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/4.0.2/) continues to use the latest [JAXB Schema Binding 3.0 Specification](https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_3_0.xsd).

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer for the forked *HiSrc* projects.

Answer (score 4):

`jaxb2-maven-plugin` version 3.0.0 will support JAXB 3. It doesn't seem to be available yet on Maven repositories, but you can get it on [github](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin/tree/jaxb2-maven-plugin-3.0.0) and install it locally.

Remark: the previous versions almost work (you just need to change their dependencies versions), but unfortunately [`AbstractJaxbMojo`](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin/blob/adac85ca47a2af77e43934623b5149da226a56d3/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxb2/AbstractJaxbMojo.java#L125) preloads some JAXB classes by name and these names changed.

Comment: Thank you. I've tested and it worked, but I'm using jaxb2-basics (https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) in my project and i't seems jaxb2-maven-plugin doesn't allow xjc plugins like maven-jaxb2-plugin. Do you know if it's possible and how?

Comment: You should be able to activate plugins through the [arguments](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/xjc-mojo.html#arguments) configuration property.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/evolvedbinary/jvnet-jaxb-maven-plugin is a fork of https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin that adds jaxb3 support, and it's published on maven central.

Your mileage may vary with jaxb2-basics depending on the specific plugin, as it doesn't support jaxb3 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently three Maven plugins that can be used to generate code from XML schemas using JAXB 3.0:

1. jakarta-jaxb-maven-plugin
2. jaxb2-maven-plugin(a fork of the maven-jaxb2-plugin)
3. org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.maven_plugin

Comment: please clarify groupId / artifactId as the plugins you mentioned cannot be found as-is in maven repos.

Answer (score 0):

The highsource project is [active again](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/issues/206) and provides [`org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools#jaxb-maven-plugin), supporting JAXB 2.3, 3.0 and 4.x.