# JDK 11: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath. issue with ContextFactory

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, java-11

I am facing an issue which many have reported with migration on JDK 11 from JDK 8 with JaxB library as JAXB classes have been removed from JDK 11. Looked at lot of useful info and tried multiple options, problem is similar to what others have experienced but all solutions described did not work unfortunately hence posting this separately.

**app is using below:**
Oracle OpenJDK 11.0.20, spring-boo: 2.6.7, maven-jaxb23-plugin: 0.15.3

- Error:
  Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
- with linked exception:
  [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
  \tat javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:232)
  \tat javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:351)
  \tat javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
  \tat javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)

Tried below solution without luck :

1. tried adding javax libs in maven based on various suggestions on stackoverflow:
   jaxb-runtime : 2.3.1
   jaxws-api 2.3.1
   jakarta.xml.bind-api: 2.3.3
   Also tried with and without jaxb-impl: 2.3.3
   all different combinations of these versions did not work.
2. Tried
   puttin jaxb-api to module path and jaxb-runtime to classpath per one of the suggestions at [link](https://github.com/jakartaee/jaxb-api/issues/78)
3. tried creating com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory to set system property as below, but did not work.
   System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory", "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory");
4. followed options with different jaxb versions without luck from this link : [jxb version link](https://mkyong.com/java/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-contextfactory/)
5. also followed some options from this link : [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632086/java-11-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-module-path-or-classpa)

Based on all research, i can see that ContextFactory class shows up in Intellij serach from javax-runtime lib with correct package name as shown in error but it doesn't take it.
So adding different jars in pom is not helping, not sure how to force jvm to use the class or lib.
Let me know if you guys have any suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: See [is-there-any-maven-plugin-for-jaxb-3-0-jakarta-ee-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66580186/is-there-any-maven-plugin-for-jaxb-3-0-jakarta-ee-9) and [what-are-the-jaxb-jar-files-to-be-used-with-java-17-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75936491/what-are-the-jaxb-jar-files-to-be-used-with-java-17-project/75949788#75949788)

Comment: Thanks @RickO'Sullivan for the links but i believe they aren't relevant with the issue i am having. Looking for some solution to use with the versions i am trying, generating of classes with plugin is not an issue for now. Somehow even with maven versions in classpath, classloader is not getting it at runtime.

Comment: @Dave Did you manage to resolve this? I am running into a similar issue and have tried everything as you.